# Hibernate+Spring accessing Websphere data source

Tags: spring, hibernate, websphere, portlet, jta

I'm working on a portal project, where I'm forced to use WebSphere Portal, Spring portlet MVC and Hibernate. I don't have much of experience in configuring neither Spring nor Hibernate, so every kind of help is  much-much appreciated.
I have created a JDBC data source on WebSphere 7.0.0.25 (with Portal 6.1 installed on it) with JNDI name jdbc/eshop. Then I specified JAAS authentication alias and set it to be container-managed authentication alias. Test connection attempt was successful, so I guess the configuration of the data source was appropriate.
My next step was making resource reference in web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>    
    <description>DB Connection</description>    
    <res-ref-name>eshop</res-ref-name>   
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>    
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>   
</resource-ref>
```

To bind res-ref-name to actual JNDI name in ibm-web-bnd I added this line:

```
<resource-ref name="eshop" binding-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/eshop" />
```

Now my Hibernate Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "HIBERNATE_TEST", schema = "SCHEME_NAME")
public class HibernateTest implements java.io.Serializable {

private short id;
private String text;

public HibernateTest() {
}

public HibernateTest(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID")
public short getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(short id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "TEXT", nullable = false, length = 10)
public String getText() {
    return this.text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}
```

HibernateTestDAO:

```
@Repository("hibernateTestDAO")
@Transactional
public class HibernateTestDAO  implements GenericDAO<HibernateTest> {
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

private Session sess;

public HibernateTestDAO ()  {

}

public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf) {
    sessionFactory = sf;
}

public boolean add(HibernateTest item) {
    boolean isAdded = false;
    try {
        sess = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        sess.persist(item);
        isAdded =  true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return isAdded;
}

public boolean edit(HibernateTest item) {
    boolean isEdited = false;
    try {
        sess = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        item = (HibernateTest)sess.merge(item);
        sess.update(item);
        isEdited =  true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return isEdited;
}

public boolean delete(HibernateTest item) {
    boolean isDeleted = false;
    try {
        sess = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        item = (HibernateTest)sess.merge(item);
        sess.delete(item);
        isDeleted =  true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return isDeleted;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<HibernateTest> getAll() {
    List<HibernateTest> l = new ArrayList<HibernateTest>(0);
    try {
        sess = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query q = sess.createQuery("FROM HibernateTest");
        l = (List<HibernateTest>) q.list();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return l;
}

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public HibernateTest getByID(long id) {
    try {
        sess = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        return (HibernateTest)sess.get(HibernateTest.class, new Short((short)id));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

As you can see, I don't want to use program-managed transactions. I have learned, that Spring has WebSphereUowTransactionManager class to manage transactions of WebSphere data sources. 
I have tried this config (applicationContext.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd    
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config /> 
    <context:component-scan base-package="test.dao,test.entities,test.portlet.controller" />

        <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/eshop"/>
    <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false"/>
    <property name="cache" value="true" />
    <property name="proxyInterface"  value="javax.sql.DataSource" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"     class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>test.entities.HibernateTest</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
          <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect</prop>
          <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
          <!--           IBM WAS SPECIFIC             -->          
          <prop key="hibernate.connection.datasource">jdbc/eshop</prop>
          <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.CMTTransactionFactory</prop>
          <prop key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup</prop>
          <prop key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform</prop> 
          <!--           /END IBM WAS SPECIFIC        -->
        </props>
    </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager">
        <property name="userTransactionName" value="java:comp/UserTransaction" />
    </bean>  

    <bean id="hibernateTestDAO" class="test.dao.HibernateTestDAO" /> 

    </beans>
```

, but it leads to this exception chain:

> Error 500: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: JTA UserTransaction is not available at JNDI location [java:comp/UserTransaction]; nested exception is org.springframework.jndi.TypeMismatchNamingException: Object of type [class com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.UserTransactionImpl] available at JNDI location [java:comp/UserTransaction] is not assignable to [javax.transaction.UserTransaction]

I know that the typical solution in this situation is to remove jta.jar from the classpath, but I don't have this jar in the classpath! 
I just don't get how IBM could use some vendor-specific library to create UserTransaction class, but I should get this worked, so I need your help to configure my application.

Also I want to add that I worked around this issue for about 3 days, tried different configs, but the was no success, sadly. So I decided to use a working (as author said) config from [this source](http://devblog.x-sphere.com/2008/01/23/websphere-jndi-spring-framework-hibernate/) as a starting point asking the question here. I have run out of ideas trying to fix this, so I need help.

**UPDATE**

I could solve the problem with Hibernate's complains about current transaction: there was no `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />` element specified, so I suppose that UOWManager didn't know when I want transaction to start. But as it turned out, it was not the end of my difficulties. 
The code of the portlet controller is below:

```
public class TestDIController extends AbstractController implements ApplicationContextAware{

private ApplicationContext appCtx;

@Override
public ModelAndView handleRenderRequest(RenderRequest request,
        RenderResponse response) throws Exception {
    appCtx = getApplicationContext();
    System.out.println(UserTransaction.class.getClassLoader());
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    GenericDAO cd = (GenericDAO)appCtx.getBean("hibernateTestDAO");
    ModelAndView m = new ModelAndView("test").addObject("list", cd.getAll());
    return m;
}
}
```

When ModelAndView instance tries to add new object to itself, HibernateTestDAO's line of code `l = (List<HibernateTest>) q.list();` throws the following exception

> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not open connection
>
> ... some stack trace...
>
> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [jcc][t4][10205][11234][3.58.81]
>   Null userid is not supported. ERRORCODE=-4461,
>   SQLSTATE=42815DSRA0010E: SQL State = 42815, Error Code = -4 461

And this error is confusing, because I have specified Container-managed authentication alias, see the picture below

[image]
where 'auth' is my JAAS-J2C authentication alias.
And when I test connection to the data source from the administrative console, it's allways successful! I do my best searching the answer to this, but up at this point there is no results. For example, the [problem described here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=452219) is pretty same to mine, but the solution doesn't suit me, because the element `<lookup-name>` is undefined in my web.xml. 
May be I should configure some J2C options, resource adapters on WebSphere, may be there is some missed configuration lines in applicationContext, who can help? I'm really confused this time.

Comment: Forgot to say, that  I use Spring 3.1.2, Hibernate 4.1.7 Final, DB2 9.7.4, sorry.

Comment: Container-managed authentication alias is only used by CMP EJBs. You'll need to configure component-managed authentication alias.

Comment: I didn't know that I couldn't use container-managed authentication. The ironical fact: component-managed authentication worked from the beginning, but I wanted to configure the inapropriate way of authentication for DB access. So I was hitting the wall for almost 2 days, that's a disappointment. Anyways, now I can access the data source from my portlet. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 5):

`com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.UserTransactionImpl` implements `javax.transaction.UserTransaction`. Your code is fine. Most probably you're using parent-last ClassLoader policy and have `javax.transaction.UserTransaction` in one of jars in your application.

Try to get rid of that `javax.transaction.UserTransaction` from your application.

Comment: You are right about parent last classloader policy. After searching into jars used by application, it seems that jboss-transaction-api_1.1.jar was responsible for this issue. However after removing that jar-file I got the following exception: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Current transaction is not in progress